# ランダムダイアリー（複数のメソッド、乱数、配列）

Tags: java, array

**■ランダムダイアリー**

0から4までのランダムな数字(重複してもOK)をそれぞれのメソッドへ引数として渡す。

> whenメソッドでは、 {"先月","先週","一昨日","昨日","今日"}   
>   whoメソッドでは、{"私は","彼女は","彼は","父は","母は"}
>    whereメソッドでは、 {"家で","お店で","海で","山で","道で"} 
>   whatメソッドでは、{"歌った","ご飯を食べた","お茶を飲んだ","泣いた","笑った"}

の配列を用い、全ての要素をmainで表示して日記を完成させる。

> ex) whenメソッドで[2]、whoメソッドで[3]、whereメソッドで[1]、
>   　　　whatメソッドで[0]を受け取った場合の結果は、
>    　　【一昨日　父は　お店で　歌った】と表示される。

---

自分なりにコーディングしてみましたが、あと一歩（かどうかはわかりませんが）のところで躓いてしまいました。
コメント文に記載してますが、//ここから～//ここまでの部分でエラーが出てしまいます。

> 「型 randamdiary のメソッド where(String) は引数 (int) に適用できません」

Stringをintに変換して引数に適用させようとしてもなかなか解消されません。
そもそもの根本的なモノが間違っている可能性がありますが、ご教授いただければと思います。

```
public class randamdiary {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int randam = (int) (Math.random() * 5);
　　　　//ここから
        String w = when(randam);
        String x = who(randam);
        String y = where(randam);
        String z = what(randam);
　　　　//ここまで
        System.out.println(w + x + w + z);
    }

    public static int when(String a) {
        String when1[] = { "先月", "先週", "一昨日", "昨日", "今日" };
        int w = 0;
        when1[w] = a;
        return Integer.parseInt(a);
    }

    public static int who(String b) {
        String who1[] = { "私は", "彼女は", "彼は", "父は", "母は" };
        int x = 0;
        who1[x] = b;
        return Integer.parseInt(b);
    }

    public static int where(String c) {
        String where1[] = { "家で", "お店で", "海で", "山で", "道で" };
        int y = 0;
        where1[y] = c;
        return Integer.parseInt(c);
    }

    public static int what(String d) {
        String what1[] = { "歌った", "ご飯を食べた", "お茶を飲んだ", "泣いた", "笑った" };
        int z = 0;
        what1[z] = d;
        return Integer.parseInt(d);
    }
}
```

Comment: `when()`メソッドや`who()`メソッドなどは、何を引数として受け取り、何を戻り値として返すのか、各メソッドの仕事を明確に（理路整然とした言葉で説明できるぐらいに）把握できていますか？　`int w = 0;`とか`when1[w] = a;`とか、その辺りの理解に混乱があるように見えます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ご自分で定義された仕様とコーディングとが一致していないようなので、もう一度確認してみてください。
以下の記述だと「引数は文字列」「返り値は数値」になってしまっています。

```java
public static int when(String a) {
    ...
}
```

実際には「引数は(ランダムな)数値」「返り値は文字列」のはずなので、少なくとも

```java
String when(int a) {
    ...
}
```

ではないでしょうか(引数を数値で渡したなら、メソッド内で`parseInt`も不要ですよね)。

---

その他の気になる点は`random`と`randam`はタイプミスなのか意図してなのかと、各メソッドを呼び出す度に`random`で値を取得してやらないと、結局四通りの文章にしかならない気がします。
(1つの値だけで4つのメソッドを呼ぶと、各配列の決まったインデックスでしか文章が構成されない)